# What is the best way to handle CAS authentication in NodeJS accross multiple route files?

Tags: node.js

I am working on an inventory management system RESTful API in NodeJS right now. The API will be accessed by a standalone VueJS application through HTTP requests. I want to use CAS to prevent access to API resources to unauthenticated users. I have settled on using the library found here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cas-authentication

I have got the library working for CAS authentication, but I have to duplicate the initializing code across all of my route files.

The initializing code I have to keep repeating:

```
const CASAuth = require('node-cas-authentication');
const cas = new CASAuth({
    cas_url     : 'https://my-cas-host.com/cas',
    service_url : 'https://my-service-host.com',
    is_dev_mode : true
});
```

My file structure:

[image: My file structure]

I wanted to know if there is a better way to organize my code so that I do not have to continuously repeat the initializing code in each file. If there is so way to include the CAS Authentication via a separate file and I require, this would be beneficial for organization and for maintenance. I am fairly new to NodeJS, so any suggestions would be helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to create a new module, say `cas-middleware.js`, which performs the initialization and exports the resulting object:

```
// cas-middleware.js
const CASAuth = require('node-cas-authentication');
const cas = new CASAuth({
    cas_url     : 'https://my-cas-host.com/cas',
    service_url : 'https://my-service-host.com',
    is_dev_mode : true
});
module.exports = cas; // Add this line
```

You can then reference that same object from all of your other modules using `require`:

```
// e.g., routes.js
const cas = require('../cas-middleware')
```

Each module that imports the object from `cas-middleware.js` will receive a reference to the same `CASAuth` object.